# Which subgroup order of the symmetric group is the most frequent?

Tags: gr.group-theory, symmetric-groups

**Question:** What is the most frequent order of subgroups of $S_n$? 
More precisely: Let $a_k$ be the number of subgroups of $S_n$ with order $k$. What is the maximum of $a_k$?

This question came up during a discussion of the open problem of determining the size of the largest antichain in the subgroup lattice of $S_n$.

Comment: "Most frequent" in terms of number of conjugacy classes of subgroups, or really in terms of number of subgroups?

Comment: In terms of number of subgroups. I will edit the question to make this obvious.

Comment: I would guess k=2.  Do you have any data or OEIS sequences?   Gerhard "Yet Another Use For Mode" Paseman, 2015.07.10

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Well I don't have any OEIS sequence for a_k, but I have one for the total number of subgroups (http://oeis.org/A005432). But k can not be small by a counting argument. The number of $2$ element subgroups is trivially at most $n!$, but the total number of subgroups has order of magnitude $c^{n^2}$, so the most frequent order by the pidgeon-hole must be at least $c^{n^2}/n!$ which is larger.

Comment: How do you prove there are $c^{n^2}$ subgroups?  It seems likely to me that by inspecting such a proof it would not be too hard to find the $k$ that maximizes $a_k$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: It seems like a difficult question actually, see the top answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76176/enumerating-all-subgroups-of-the-symmetric-group

Comment: @EricWofsey Well I can't prove it I just read it at OEIS. Here is the proof, (http://www.jstor.org/stable/2946623?seq=8#page_scan_tab_contents) I think the lower bound suggests that we look at the cases where $k$ is a power of two. (Maybe this effect is the reason Gerhard Paseman had two in his mind.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is already sort of in the comments, but just to say it clearly:

In the paper Enumerating Finite Groups of Given Order
Author(s): L. Pyber
Source: Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 137, No. 1 (Jan., 1993), pp. 203-220

Pyber proves that the number of subgroups of $S_n$ is bounded below by $2^{(1/16 + o(1))n^2}.$ He shows this by noting that $S_n$ contains $C_2^{[\frac{n}2]},$ and the latter has the specified number of subgroups. He then conjectures that the lower bound is, in fact, sharp. In other words, modulo this conjecture, at least morally, the maximally present order of a subgroup is, indeed, a power of two, and the actual power of two  is presumably $2^{[[\frac{n}2]/2]}.$ It seems that Pyber's conjecture is still open.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Of course, I meant "maximally abundant order of subgroup", I have fixed now, thanks!