# The number of subgroups of ${\frak S}_n$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Because of my interest in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/108530), I listed the subgroups of ${\frak S}_n$ for $1\le n\le4$. I found that the number of subgroups are, respectively, $1,2,6,24$. It might be a coincidence, or it could reveal a deep connection.

> Is it always the case that ${\frak S}_n$ has exactly $n!$ (non-proper) subgroups ?

**Edit**. Because of my erroneous claim about ${\frak S}_4$, I tried to delete the question. But this cannot be done once an answer has been posted. So I asked the help of the front desk. Decision is pending.

Comment: Are you sure of your computations?

According to http://oeis.org/A005432, the group $S_4$ has $30$ distinct subgroups, not $24$.

Comment: Taken from an answer on MSE :http://math.stackexchange.com/q/76176 The number of distinct subgroups of the symmetric group on n points are given for n ≤ 13 in oeis:A005432 (and I checked by hand that the number of subgroups of $S_{4}$ is indeed $30$).

Comment: Yeah, questions really should not be deleted with upvoted/accepted answers, except under extraordinary circumstances. Errors in the post don't by themselves merit a deletion; I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Francesco Polizzi mentions, the answer is no alredy for ${\frak S}_4$: there are $30$ subgroups, but $4!=24$.

Here are some more (very small) calculations:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathrm{group}& \mathrm{\# subgroups} & n! \\ \hline
{\frak S}_1 & 1 &1\\ \hline
{\frak S}_2 & 2 &2\\ \hline
{\frak S}_3 & 6 &6\\ \hline
{\frak S}_4 & 30 &24\\ \hline
{\frak S}_5 & 156 &120\\ \hline
{\frak S}_6 & 1455 & 720\\ \hline
{\frak S}_7 & 11300 & 5040\\ \hline
{\frak S}_8 & 151221 & 40320\\ \hline
{\frak S}_9 & 1694723 & 362880\\ \hline
\end{array}

You can find the number of subgroups up to ${\frak S}_{18}$ in here:

- Derek Holt, [Enumerating subgroups of the symmetric group](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~mareg/download/papers/symsubs/symsubs.pdf)

Also, according to [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79139) math.stackexchange, the asymptotics for the number of subgroups is $\log(\#\text{sub}) = \Theta(n^2)$.

As for the number of subgroups for arbitrary ${\frak S}_n$, the problem seems wide open.

Answer (score 12):

If you look at my answer to [this question,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211260/which-subgroup-order-of-the-symmetric-group-is-the-most-frequent/211263#211263) you will see that the number of proper subgroups grows *at least* as fast as $2^{n^2/6},$ so **much** faster than $n!.$ This is a result of Laci Pyber.

Comment: The MSE answer I mentioned in my comment to the original question also mentions this asymptotic behaviour.